# Javascript canvas multiply arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, canvas, rendering

I have big problem with this. It work what I want, but when ball touch floor and I call function again to restart game it create new array. That make problem with counting score(rezultat). I try to clear array after lose, but he duplicate it. I know that for loop need to be outside of function, but than I cant restart it when 'P' is pressed on line 149. Here is code https://jsfiddle.net/slavko993/2bq5w7oc/. pedala() --> paddle, lopta() --> ball, kretanje() -->nacrtajCigle() --> drawBricks, kontakt --> collision().

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
    });

function igra(){

    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var igrac = {
        x : canvas.width / 2 - 40,
        y : canvas.height - 10,
        sirina : 80,
        visina : 8,
        velX : 0,
        brzina : 5,
        trenje : 0.8
    };
    var krug = {
        x : 0,
        y : canvas.height - 26,
        dx : 8,
        dy : -8
    };
    cigla = {
        red : 9,
        kolona : 4,
        sirina : 80,
        visina : 20,
    };
    var keys = [];
    cigle = [];
    rezultat = 0;
    var pusti = new Image();
    var ponovi = new Image();

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
        keys[e.keyCode] = true;
        if(keys[37]){
            document.getElementById('levo').style.backgroundColor = '#27ae60';
            document.getElementById('levo').style.borderColor = '#27ae60';
        }
        if(keys[39]){
            document.getElementById('desno').style.backgroundColor = '#27ae60';
            document.getElementById('desno').style.borderColor = '#27ae60';
        }
    });
    document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
        keys[e.keyCode] = false;
        if(!keys[37]){
            document.getElementById('levo').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
            document.getElementById('levo').style.borderColor = '#a0a0a0';
        }
        if(!keys[39]){
            document.getElementById('desno').style.backgroundColor = '#a0a0a0';
            document.getElementById('desno').style.borderColor = '#a0a0a0';
        }
    });

    for(var k = 0; k < cigla.kolona; k++){
        cigle[k] = [];
            for(var r = 0; r < cigla.red; r++){
                cigle[k][r] = {x : 0, y : 0, status : 1};
            }
    }

    function kontakt(){
        for(var k = 0; k < cigla.kolona; k++){
            for(var r = 0; r < cigla.red; r++){
                var obj = cigle[k][r];
                if(obj.status == 1){
                if(krug.x > obj.x && krug.x < obj.x + cigla.sirina && krug.y > obj.y && krug.y < obj.y + cigla.visina){
                    krug.dy = -krug.dy;
                    obj.status = 0;
                    rezultat++;
                    document.getElementById('rezultat').value = rezultat;

                    if(rezultat == cigla.red * cigla.kolona){
                        document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
                            //naredni nivo
                            ctx.beginPath();
                            ctx.font = 'bold 30pt Arial';
                            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                            ctx.fillStyle = '#8e44ad';
                            ctx.fillText('Imate: ' + rezultat + 'poen/a', canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
                            ctx.closePath();
                            //naredni nivo kraj
                            keys[e.keyCode] = true;
                            if(keys[83]){

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function kretanje(){
        if(keys[37]){
            if(igrac.velX > -igrac.brzina){
                igrac.velX--;
            }
        }
        if(keys[39]){
            if(igrac.velX < igrac.brzina){
                igrac.velX++;
            }
        }

        igrac.velX *= igrac.trenje;
        igrac.x += 3*igrac.velX;

        if(igrac.x <= 0){
            igrac.x = 0;
        }
        else if(igrac.x >= canvas.width - igrac.sirina){
            igrac.x = canvas.width - igrac.sirina;
        }
    }

    function kraj(){
        //tekst
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.font = 'bold 30pt Arial';
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.fillStyle = '#8e44ad';
        ctx.fillText(localStorage.ime + ', osvojili ste: ' + rezultat + ' poen/a', canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
        ctx.closePath();
        //tekst kraj
        //ponovi
        ctx.beginPath();
        ponovi.src = 'ponovi.png';
        ctx.drawImage(ponovi, canvas.width/2 - 28, canvas.height/2 + 30, 54, 54);
        ctx.closePath();
        //ponovi kraj
        //igraj ponovo tekst
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.font = '15pt Arial';
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.fillStyle = '#0090ff';
        ctx.fillText('Igraj ponovo(P)', canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2 + 115);
        ctx.closePath();
        //igraj ponovo tekst kraj
        //ponovi
        console.log(cigle);
        document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
            keys[e.keyCode] = true;
            if(keys[80]){
                igra();
            }
        });
        //ponovi kraj
    }

    function lopta(){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(krug.x, krug.y, 8, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = '#2c3e50';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    function pedala(){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(igrac.x, igrac.y, igrac.sirina, igrac.visina);
        ctx.fillStyle = '#2c3e50';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    function nacrtajCigle(){
        for(var k = 0; k < cigla.kolona; k++){
            for(var r = 0; r < cigla.red; r++){
            if(cigle[k][r].status == 1){
                var x = r*(cigla.sirina + 15) + 60;
                var y = k*(cigla.visina + 15) + 30;
                cigle[k][r].x = x;
                cigle[k][r].y = y;
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.rect(x, y, cigla.sirina, cigla.visina);
                ctx.fillStyle = '#c0392b';
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.closePath();
            }
            }
        }
    }

    function iscrtavanje(){
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        pedala();
        lopta();
        kretanje();
        nacrtajCigle();
        kontakt();

        krug.x += krug.dx;
        krug.y += krug.dy;

        if(krug.x + krug.dx >= canvas.width - 8){
            krug.dx = -krug.dx;
        }
        else if(krug.x + krug.dx <= 0 + 8){
            krug.dx = -krug.dx;
        }
        else if(krug.y + krug.dy <= 0 + 8){
            krug.dy = -krug.dy;
        }
        else if(krug.y + krug.dy >= canvas.height - 15){
            if(krug.x > igrac.x && krug.x < igrac.x + igrac.sirina || krug.y > igrac.y && krug.y < igrac.y + igrac.height){
                krug.dy = -krug.dy;
            }
            else if(krug.y + krug.dy >= canvas.height){
                //kutija
                setTimeout(kraj, 500);
                return false;
        }
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(iscrtavanje);
    }

    iscrtavanje();


}
    igra();
```

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you named variables in English.

Comment: Uh, ova loptica je prebrza za mene. :) -> This ball is too fast for me. Don't know solution, but, after few games, i've noticed, script becomes buggy, ball is slowing down (memory resources hungry script?)So, plain page refresh/reload (on P click) could solve it, and also - points problem could be solved that way? :)